# Oracle Apex: Display different links in cell of table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have using oracle apex to create an application.

Is there a way to make a table cell display different links based on what is inside the cell?

So I want to have an icon '+' that is linked to a 'create' page inside the cells that are empty.

This is an interactive report for apex.

[image]

but I already set the asset column as a link to a 'edit' page

[image]

Here is the code to generate the data:

```
select ID,
(SELECT distinct listagg(v.asset_id,', ') within group (order by s.id) from subnet_lookup l, infra_assets_master v where l.subnet_id = s.id AND l.link_id = v.id AND l.def_id = 3) as Assets,
(SELECT distinct listagg(v.hostname,', ') within group (order by s.id) from subnet_lookup l, infra_assets_master v where l.subnet_id = s.id AND l.link_id = v.id AND l.def_id = 3) as Hostname,
(SELECT distinct listagg(m.hostname,', ') within group (order by s.id) from subnet_lookup l, servers_master m where l.subnet_id = s.id AND l.link_id = m.id AND l.def_id = 1) as Servers,

from subnet s 
where NETWORK_ID = :P55_NETWORK_ID
ORDER BY ID desc
```

Is there a way I can set a condition to display different information with different links based on the values inside the cell?

Comment: Is this a report or an interactive grid or some custom table?  Can you show us the sql statement that is generating the data?

Comment: @RLOG This is a interactive report